# What are Water Vapour Resistant (WVR) engine bags made from?

Tags: jet-engine, aerospace-materials

What specific material are Water Vapour Resistant (WVR) engine bags made from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specifics will depend on the product. [Bags by Aerotest](http://aerotest.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/3rd-Proof-LM2500-Engine-Water-Vapour-Resistant-WVR-Aero-Bag-PS.pdf) are made from supported PVC textile and coated with acrylic lacquer.

Comment: Do you know what type of material they use?